# When uploading a project to an open source repository, should one remove the bin and obj folders?

Tags: c#, open-source, standards

Just wondering what the standard practice is. Removing these folders before uploading makes the downloaded files easier to sort through and reduces the file count and size of the project (faster download). However, the downloader has to rebuild it to run it in his IDE of choice (in this case, VC#).

I will most likely have a separate download for the compiled binary so I imagine that removing the bin and obj folders would be desirable? Also, removing these folders remove all exe's and compiled files from the source code so they can be shared by services such as Gmail (Gmail does not allow emailing executables) without hassle.

Answer (score 3):

yes, the obj and bin folders are generated by build process and are not needed by other developers to open the solution and rebuild the projects.

in general you should strip out also .suo files and other user specific files Visual Studio could create locally.

Comment: Currently I am using VC# Express. Is that this file? "ProjectName.csproj.user". Also, is there anything else I should remove? Perhaps something in the Properties folder?

Comment: Hi, properties are ok, .user yes, you should remove.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should remove the binaries. As you said, you can offer separate binaries to download. If you have binaries in your version control repository, it also adds a bunch of unneeded file changes to your source control, making it harder sometimes to see what the real changes are.